# Filtering junk mail on iPad

Tags: ipad

Is it possible to filter-out junk mail before it reaches my I-pad-mini's inbox - as Outlook does on my laptop?

#### As mentioned in the above question, my e-mail programme is Outlook.

Oops, sorry - my e-mail provider is TalkTalk.

Comment: What email provider are you using? Gmail, Yahoo, Exchange, or something else? Your iPad doesn't provide junk filtering like Outlook. If your email hosting service has a spam filtering service, then it will do that for you, but iPad can't.

Comment: To see what Junk mail processing you can change log into your mail providers web mail

Answer (score 1):

Use Gmail as a POP client to your mail server, and use Gmail App.

Gmail spam filter is awesome. I see less than 10 spam emails a year...

Answer (score 0):

The iPad doesn't have any spam filtering on it.

It appears that TalkTalk doesn't have any spam filtering. You may want to log in to your account online to make sure you can't setup filtering there.

What you can do is make sure that you have your TalkTalk email setup on your iPad as an IMAP email account. Then, as long as your computer receives the email (it is on, and doing refreshes), it should filter the mail, and consequently move it to the proper (junk) folders. Then, when you refresh email on your iPad, the changes should reflect properly there.